# REST Web Services API Design

Tags: rest

Just wanted to get feedback on how I am planning to architect my API. Dummy methods below. Here's the structure:

```
GET http://api.domain.com/1/users/ <-- returns a list of users
POST http://api.domain.com/1/users/add.xml <-- adds user
POST http://api.domain.com/1/users/update.xml <-- updates user
DELETE (or POST?) http://api.domain.com/1/users/delete.xml <-- deletes user
```

Questions:

1. Is it OK to use just GET and POST?
2. Is it a good idea that I plan to rely on the filename to indicate what operation to do (e.g. add.xml to add)? Would it be better to do something like this: POST http://api.domain.com/1/users/add/data.xml?
3. What's a good way to keep these resources versioned? In my example, I use a /1/ after domain name to indicate version 1. Alternatives would be: http://api1.domain.com... or http://api-1.domain.com... or http://apiv1.domain.com... or http://api-v1.domain.com... or http://api.domain.com/v1/... or
4. What's the best way to authenticate?

Comment: [REST API Architecture – Best Practices](http://dasunhegoda.com/rest-api-architecture-best-practices/1049/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) On your design probably not. POST is not idempotent! So you should not use for the update or the delete, instead use PUT and DELETE from Rest

2) A better choice is to use the header *Content-Type* on the WS call, like: application/xml

3) Also on the header Content-Type u can use it: application-v1.0/xml

4) Not sure if it is the best, but probably the easiest way is to use HTTP's built-in authentication mechanisms in [RFC 2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt). An example: [AWS Authentication](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html)

Comment: your reasoning on (1) is weak. POST is not "not idempotent", it is "not necessarily idempotent". Since he defines the server-side semantic, his POST might be idempotent and that is cool with http and the world at large.

Comment: @NasBanov From the w3.org Http Methods documentation http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html. Take a look at section 9.1.2 Idempotent Methods. Post is never shown as a possible Idempotent Method.

Comment: @DiegoDias, 9.1.2 talks about GET/HEAD/PUT/DELETE, there are no implications on POST. If i say that Joe and Moe are honest, that does not make Billy a liar. [9.5] "The actual function performed by the POST method is determined by the server and is usually dependent on the Request-URI" - If for example i have a (flip-flop) light switch there, it will not be idempotent. But if it was an "ON" button instead, it will be idempotent

Comment: See section 9.6: "The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed entity. ... In contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request". So if you want to use PUT, you need to know userID in advance and do `PUT http://api.domain.com/1/user/123654`. If you would expect to add user and get ID in return, you should be doing `POST http://api.domain.com/1/users`

Answer (score 39):

Before you dig into REST, here are some terms you really need to grasp:

> Resource - The things/data you want to make available in your API (in your case a "User")
>
> URI - A universally unique ID **for a resource**.  Should mention nothing about the method being performed (e.g. shouldn't contain "add" or "delete").  The structure of your URI however doesn't make your app any more or less RESTful - this is a common misconception.
>
> Uniform Interface - A fixed set of *operations* you can perform on your resources, in most cases this is [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).  There are clear definitions for the purpose of each of these HTTP methods.

The most unrestful thing about your URIs as they are right now is that they have information about the operation being performed right in them.  URIs are IDs and nothing more!

Let's take a real world example.  My name is Nathan.  "Nathan" could be considered my ID (or in restful terms URI – for the purpose of this example assume I'm the only "Nathan").  My name/ID doesn't changed based on how you would like to interact with me, e.g. My name wouldn't change to "NathanSayHello" when you wanted to greet me.

It's the same for REST.  Your user identified by http://api.domain.com/users/1 doesn't change to http://api.domain.com/users/1/update.xml when you want to update that user.  The fact that you want to update that user is implied by the method you're using (e.g. PUT).

Here is my suggestion for your URIs

```
# Retrieve info about a user 
GET http://api.domain.com/user/<id>

# Retrieve set all users
GET http://api.domain.com/users

# Update the user IDed by api.domain.com/user/<id>
PUT http://api.domain.com/user/<id>

# Create a new user.  The details (even <id>) are based as the body of the request
POST http://api.domain.com/users

# Delete the user ID'd by api.domain.com/user/<id>
DELETE http://api.domain.com/user/<id>
```

As for your questions:

1. Use PUT and DELETE when appropriate and avoid overloading POST to handle these functions as it breaks [HTTP's definition of POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5).  HTTP is your uniform interface.  It is your contract with the API user about how they can expect to interact with your service.  If you break HTTP, you break this contract.
2. Remove "add" altogether.  Use HTTP's Content-Type header for specifying the mime-type of posted data.
3. Are you referring to the version of your API or the version of the resource?  ETag and other response headers can be used to version the resources.
4. Many options here.  Basic HTTP Auth (easy but insecure), Digest Auth, custom auth like AWS.  OAuth is also a possibility.  If security is of main importance, I use client side SSL certs.

Comment: +1 on reply, but: PUT/DELETE are required to be idempotent, not POST. POST can be whatever it pleases. "Idempotent" just means that if the operation is repeated twice, it produces the same result - in math speak that's `f(f(x)) = f(x)`. In our case if one does two identical PUTs to the same resource, the result must be the same as if only 1 was done. POST on the other hand, depending on the semantic given by developer, can have different outcomes (e.g. POST twice may send 2 emails)

Comment: you are totally right.  that should read "general lack of idempotence", seeing as more often than not it is creating a resources (or in your example a job to send an email) which definitely is not idempotent.  will adjust post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. In REST, the HTTP "verb" is used to denote the operation type: you won't be able to express all the CRUD operations with only "GET" and "POST"
2. no: the URL of the resource is usually where the "document identifier" should appear
3. The version of the "document" can be transmitted in an HTTP response header upon creation/modification of the said resource.  It should be the duty of the server to uniquely identify the resources - trying to do this on the client side will prove a daunting challenge i.e. keeping consistency.

Of course, there are many variations on the topic...

Answer (score 0):

I did authentication based on headers. Something like

```
X-Username:happy-hamster
X-Password:notmyactualpassword
```

If you're concerned about security - do it through SSL.
Other implementations exist, of course. For instance, Amazon with their S3:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html

If you don't have ability to make PUT and DELETE requests, it's considered a good practice to tunnel them through POST. In this case the action is specified in URL. If I recall correctly, RoR does exactly this:

```
POST http://example.com/foos/2.xml/delete
```

or

```
POST http://example.com/foos/3.xml/put

...

<foo>
    <bar>newbar</bar>       
</foo>
```

It's a bit offtop, but in regards to versioning and REST overall you might want to take a look at [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). Here is a [good book available on-line](http://books.couchdb.org/relax)

Answer (score -1):

Using post for create and delete functionality is not a good rest api design strategy. Use Put to create, post to update and delete to delete the resources.
For more information on designing rest apis follow the link - [*best practices to design rest apis*](https://simpledevsolutions.blogspot.com/2020/04/rest-api-naming-conventions.html)